# Showing Cocoa app's preferences on clicking app icon again

Tags: cocoa, macos

For a background app (LSUIElement=1), what's the most elegant way to make its 'preferences' or 'configuration' window pop up if a user double-clicks the app icon while it's already running?

This is assuming the user cannot access the app's prefs from anywhere else (such as menu bar status item menus).

I would suppose the ideal method would prevent the prefs window from showing on initial start, but is smart enough to show it on subsequent double-clicks on the app's icon.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to implement an `NSApplicationDelegate` protocol method [`applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW23).

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
{
     // open pref pane
     return NO;
}
```

would suffice; this delegate method is only called when the app is re-opened.

Comment: So obvious now! I went over the NSApplicationDelegate protocol and completely missed this one. That's for coding past 2am :)